# Query an Array of Embedded Documents

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

A test collection has one document.

```
db.test.insert({
     "_id" : ObjectId("5922bd14ff3ee9313229ac18"),
     "O" : [
             {
                     "A" : "Field_1",
                     "B" : "Unknown"
             },
             {
                     "A" : "Field_2",
                     "B" : "Unknown_Location"
             }
     ]
```

})

I want this entry to return only if both the A and the B filter's match in one of the documents.

For example, TEST CASE 1:

```
db.test.find({"O.A" : "Field_2", "O.B" : "Unknown_Location"}).count()
1
db.test.find({"O.A" : "Field_1", "O.B" : "Unknown"}).count()
1
```

TEST CASE 2
But the following query also returns this entry, for which causes problems:

```
db.test.find({"O.A" : "Field_1", "O.B" : "Unknown_Location"}).count()
1
```

Help is sincerely appreciated.

This question is different from [Retrieve only the queried element in an object array in MongoDB collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985214/retrieve-only-the-queried-element-in-an-object-array-in-mongodb-collection)
In that question, the question was to retrieve a part and was solved by projecting a part of matched document.

My Problem is that the match in the TEST CASE 2 is unwanted and I need to change my query accordingly.

Comment: @neil-lunn Have explained why the question is different

Comment: How? `{ "O": { "$elemMatch": { "A": "Field_1", "B": "Unknown_Location" } } }` will not match any **document** since there is no array element matching those conditions. You also nee `$elemMatch` otherwise the statement matches *"any position in the array"*, so you use it for the combination of keys. If you are asking *"How to retrieve just the matched elements ( in plural )"* then there are aggregation examples showing `$filter` there. Same question. If you really think differently, then explain your difference in your question. But I think you should try using the correct query expressions.

Comment: You are right, db.test.find( { "O": { $elemMatch: { A: "Field_1", B: "Unknown_Location" } } } ) does solve the issue.

Does $elemMatch use indexes, and can it be optimized? Or does it need to scan all?

Comment: Yes it can use an index. You can read the documentation [`$elemMatch`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) along with various similar documentation links included in the linked question.